# Set JLabel Alignment right-left

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, right-to-left, bidi

I have a JPanel that separated to 2 blocks, in south block (layout) I have add a JLabel, In the label I want to Insert a string with this rule: `(Name, Date, Time, In/Out)`

If my name was written in English everything was fine the problem appeared when I wrote the name in some Unicode language like Farsi, then the alignment not working as expected.
I attach 2 sample:

Right one:
[image]

Wrong one:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create two different labels next to each other. One for the name and one for the remaining part. This way, the alignment of the name label won't affect the alignment of the other label.

Comment: Tanx, yes your solution is right but I want to know can I fix this problem with 1 label?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux well great idea, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Component.setComponentOrientation()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setComponentOrientation%28java.awt.ComponentOrientation%29) on the label to force it to left-to-right order.